# btnactionsender in xcode 8 instead of btnaction

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, xcode, ipad

I have updated Xcode to 8 and in my code there is a button action named  `@IBAction func M_CtrlBtnTouchupInside(sender: AnyObject)`
but in the story board it shows as `M_CtrlBtnTouchupInsideSender` when i connect it to the button it shows error  `unrecognized selector sent to instance` , It was working fine before xcode update

Comment: Remove the connection of M_CtrlBtnTouchupInsideSender from storyboard.

Answer (score 0):

1. Just add "_" to beginning of your function:

   `@IBAction func M_CtrlBtnTouchupInside(_ sender: AnyObject`
2. Make connection through Interface Builder
3. Remove "_"

Answer (score 0):

I got corrected it by removing `sender: AnyObject`

```
@IBAction func M_CtrlBtnTouchupInside()
```

worked